# How do I apply my filter only to one store/url?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been struggling applying filters to my woocommerce shop. I have a website with multiple store pages and I've found a filter to only shop products published within the last 30 days. I want this filter to only apply to the 'new releases' shoppage, not to the whole website. Currently it's filtering everything, so even pages created before last month won't appear for example.

How do I make sure this filter is only applied to 1 store? Can I apply an IF statement and check current URL before the filter works or something?

Any help is appreciated.

Filter: (from https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/show-latest-30-days-products-in-woocommerce/258276)

```
function baba_recent_products() {
    //return 'This is where the recent products should show up if I get the shortcode working. ';
    
    
    global $woocommerce_loop;

        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'per_page'  => '48',
            'columns'   => '2',
            'orderby'   => 'date',
            'order'     => 'desc'
        ), $atts ) );

        $meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

        $args = array(
            'post_type'             => 'product',               
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
            'posts_per_page'        => $per_page,
            'orderby'               => $orderby,
            'order'                 => $order,
            'meta_query'            => $meta_query
        );

        ob_start();

        $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }
    
    
    add_shortcode( 'baba_recent_products', 'baba_recent_products' );

function filter_where($where = '') {
    //posts in the last 30 days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

Comment: How are the "Shop" pages displaying the products are they using a template file ? or are you using a widget or short code?

Comment: There are multiple pages using the same woocommerece shop template, since the webpages have different URL, I assume you can create an IF statement, so it would only apply on that one shop.

Comment: you could use `global $post;` and then use `$post->post_name` to check for the pages slug or `$post->ID` the slug may change so the id is probably the best option

Answer (score 0):

```
function baba_recent_products() {
    //return 'This is where the recent products should show up if I get the shortcode working. ';
    
    global $woocommerce_loop;

        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'per_page'  => '48',
            'columns'   => '2',
            'orderby'   => 'date',
            'order'     => 'desc'
        ), $atts ) );

        $meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

        $args = array(
            'post_type'             => 'product',               
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
            'posts_per_page'        => $per_page,
            'orderby'               => $orderby,
            'order'                 => $order,
            'meta_query'            => $meta_query
        );

        ob_start();

        $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }
    
    
    add_shortcode( 'baba_recent_products', 'baba_recent_products' );

function filter_where($where = '') {
    global $post;
    if($post->ID === /*Page ID as int here*/){
        //posts in the last 30 days
        $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```